# How do you manage component dependency order with Facebook React?

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs

Say I have two React Components, A and B, where B depends upon (makes use of) A. Say that A is in a.js and B is in b.js .

Is there a way in React to safely resolve a dependency from B to A? Thereby guaranteeing that regardless of what order I actually include a.js and b.js, things will still resolve correctly?

I believe that the Google Closure compiler effectively fakes a dependency system for you in both development and production mode. This makes the order that different code is included in the source irrelevant; is there something like this for React?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Note: the answer below is very outdated.
>
> I stopped using RequireJS a long time ago due to the fact that it gets rather slow in development because doesn’t bundle JS in a single file in development.
>
> These days I’m mostly [using Webpack](https://github.com/petehunt/webpack-howto).
> You may also consider other bundlers such as [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) and [Rollup](http://rollupjs.org).
>
> I use [ES modules](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html) as the module system, [transpiled](http://www.2ality.com/2015/12/babel-commonjs.html) by [Babel](http://babeljs.io) into CommonJS. Eventually I plan to swich to ES modules completely as more bundlers with its first-class support, such as Rollup and Webpack 2, become mainstream.

---

### Old Answer

To my knowledge, React itself doesn't provide any dependency management system; if you need one, you must use some existing tool that fits your workflow.

Personally, I'm happy using [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org) with [AMD sugar syntax](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar) so my modules look like this:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
/* jshint trailing:false, quotmark:false, newcap:false */
define(function (require) {

  'use strict';

  var React = require('react'),
      _ = require('underscore'),
      JoinWidget = require('common/views/join_widget');

  var LoginWidget = React.createClass({
    // ...
  });
});
```

Each React view, as any other class, gets its own file.

This is fine in development environment but I don't want to load scripts on the fly in production, so I use grunt-requirejs task with [almond](https://github.com/jrburke/almond) to concatenate files in proper order so they are always loaded synchronously in a single file.